# Setting up registers for cmpxchg16b in ASM

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers

I'm trying to use the lock cmpxchg16b instruction to do an atomic compare and swap in an external function in C.
The call to the function has 3 128 bit objects, of which I want to compare the first 2, and replace with the third one should they equal each other.

These are my parameters from what I gather:

rdi: old status

rsi: cur status

rdx: mod status

Now, what I want to do is have rdi (shouldn't there be a second half of this?) loaded into rax, and the second half of this status loaded into rdx. (rdi+8??)

If what I'm doing there is right then rdx would be compared to rsi and rax to rsi+8 when doing

```
lock cmpxchg16b (%rsi)
```

right? Since it's little endian

But how do I move rdi to rdx:rax?
I've tried this:

```
movq (%rdi), %rdx
```

and

```
movq %rdi, %rdx
```

But I can't seem to get it working, it's always spewing out that they're not equal even when running it with the same object twice.

Full function right now:

```
my_cmpr_swap:
    #save rbx as we need the register
    pushq %rbx
    # set up registers rdx:rax
    movq %rdx, (%rdi)
    #compare-swap
    lock cmpxchg16b (%rsi)

    #return 1 if success, 0 if not
    jz success
    movq $0,%rax
    jmp end
success:
    movq $1,%rax
end:
    popq %rbx
    ret
```

Comment: You didn’t mention rbx and rcx, which cmpxchg16b also uses. I think you need to reread the instruction description. Also, please post your full function, not excerpts. It’s only a few lines.

Comment: @prl rcx:rbx is copied into register you specify (here rsi and rsi+8), should the comparison succeed, yeah, but I'm not too concerned with that till I can actually get rdx:rax set up for the proper comparison. I've edited in the full function as I have it right now.

Comment: You talk about setting up `rdx:rax` but you have no code that sets up `rax‘.

Comment: @RaymondChen I don't, no, because after having searched around I still can't seem to find which register to reference for the second half of rdi, that would go into well, rdx, and then rdi would go to rax.

Comment: It's wasn't clear what you meant by "the second half of rdi". rdi is a 64-bit register. There is no second half of it that contains the other 64 bits. Or is rdi a pointer to a 128-bit value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes you're passing the old and new values by reference.

```
my_cmpr_swap:
    #save rbx as we need the register
    pushq %rbx

    # set up registers rcx:rbx
    movq (%rdx), %rbx
    movq 8(%rdx), %rcx

    # set up registers rdx:rax
    movq (%rdi), %rax
    movq 8(%rdi), %rdx

    #compare-swap
    lock cmpxchg16b (%rsi)

    #return 1 if success, 0 if not
    jz success

    # store updated rdx:rax
    movq %rax, (%rdi)
    movq %rdx, 8(%rdi)

    movq $0,%rax
    jmp end
success:
    movq $1,%rax
end:
    popq %rbx
    ret
```

Answer (score -1):

This answer assumes you're passing the old and new values by value.

```
my_cmpr_swap:
    #save rbx as we need the register
    pushq %rbx

    mov %rdx, %r10

    # set up registers rcx:rbx
    movq %rcx, %rbx
    movq %r8, %rcx

    # set up registers rdx:rax
    movq %rdi, %rax
    movq %rsi, %rdx

    #compare-swap
    lock cmpxchg16b (%r10)

    #return 1 if success, 0 if not
    jz success

    movq $0,%rax
    jmp end
success:
    movq $1,%rax
end:
    popq %rbx
    ret
```